# Using Jcolorchooser to paint graphs in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, graph, colors, jcolorchooser

I'm writing a program for drawing graphs from user entered inputs.
so the user will give the program a mathematical expression like ADD(X,Y)
then the user will choose the range of a variable and set the value of another variable as the color variable that has a value (that is [RGB Int](http://www.shodor.org/stella2java/rgbint.html)  or any combination of rgb colors that can be converted to a single number that can be used in the expression) .

I'm using Jcolorchooser for this so the user can click on the his/her preferred color . 
my question is how can I store the value of the color so I can set the graph color with that value .
finally the user can click on four different colors and four graphs with the colors and their value will be drawn(using paintcomponent).
is it possible to make Jcolorchooser to store multiple clicks' data and values in some fields for the program I want to make.

Update: this is an example of how graphs should be drawn .
It's very crude right now I know but I'm asking specifically for storing Jcolorchooser data made from clicks on the colors

the Jpanel class:

```
 package progGUI;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class drawpanel extends JPanel {

public void paintComponent( Graphics g) {
super.paintComponents(g);
this.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
g.drawLine(21, 20, 60, 60);
   }

 }
```

The frame class:

```
frame.add(drawpanel);
package paneltest;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class main extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
pan1 pan = new pan1();
frame.add(pan);
frame.setVisible(true);

   }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code to show us what you have so far? We can better answer your question with some context.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. 
if you just want to find good graphs, JFreeChart is really easy to use and has a lot of options. Check [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) this might be what you need.